# Why does yocto scipy recipe require python3 explicitly set? How?

Tags: python, yocto, bitbake

I have a recipe to build scipy which parses fine and bitbake starts building but the python3 
version requirement is not met. It exits with

```
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "setup.py", line 31, in <module>
|     raise RuntimeError("Python version >= 3.5 required.")
| RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/marius/mender-qemu/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/python3-scipy/1.4.1-r0/temp/log.do_configure.30478)
```

I successfully built other python3 packages which can be imported in the running image. You can also see from the path that python3 is used and the image runs on python3.5. I'm using `thud`.

For the sake of completion here is the recipe. I also tried explicitly adding dependencies (numpy) but that did not have any effect.

```
SUMMARY = "Scipy summary to be filled"
DESCRIPTION = "Scientific computing"
PYPI_PACKAGE = "scipy"

LICENSE = "BSD"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE.txt;md5=011ccf01b7e0590d9435a864fc6a4d2b"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "3a97689656f33f67614000459ec08585"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "dee1bbf3a6c8f73b6b218cb28eed8dd13347ea2f87d572ce19b289d6fd3fbc59"
```

This is the python-scipy.inc

```
inherit setuptools3 distutils
require python-scipy.inc
```

Also, I tried to add `inherit python3native` without effect.

My question is: how can I explicitly set python3 to build this recipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple and obvious solution was to `inherit distutils3` instead of `inherit distutils`.

**NOTE**: A python-scipy recipe that worked out of the box for me can be found here: https://github.com/gpanders/oe-scipy

Nice job gpanders!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you run a python script setup.py as part of your build that requires python3 on your host(the system that build Yocto).

You can install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Python3 is already installed on the host and bitbake runs on that as far as I understand. To make sure: How can I confirm what python version is fired up?

Comment: As a follow up: other recipes build fine for python3. I also experimented e.g. with `inherit python3native` but that did not have any effect.

Comment: I am guessing that Yocto uses the default python, you can check what it is by running "which python". your script might define which python it uses as well. It should look something like "#!/usr/bin/env python3"

Comment: What do you mean with "your script"? The bitbake receipe? To clarify: I'm rather experienced with python. That is not the issue. It's more related to bitbake.

Comment: The error is in the "setup.py" script, I am not sure whose script it is. I don't remember it being part of Yocto(or I just never had an issue with it)

Comment: The setup.py is scipy's setup.py that is pulled from pypi as the recipe indicates. Thus, the setup.py is not the issue. It's rather my recipe. I need to declare a runtime dependency to use python3. I tried `RDEPENDS_${PN} += " python3 python3-numpy"` but that does not seem to have an effect.

Comment: this script is running from "#!/usr/bin/env python", the "python" file in that dir is typically a link file that points to another file. I am guessing that in your system it points to python2.7(or some other version) instead of python3.6 which is required by that script: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/setup.py